# How to put a values in assigned space inside a string from other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've two tables.
Name of first is, let's say, Table_A:

| A_ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My name is {0}, and surname {1} |
| 2 | I live in [city:0] |
| ... | ... |

Second one is Table_B:

| B_ID | Number | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | John |
| 1 | 1 | Smith |
| 2 | 0 | LA |
| ... | ... |  |

Column A_ID in Table_A is unique, but  B_ID is not. Also, B_ID is foreign key.
Additionally, parameters such as {0} or {1} might be different, i.e [str:0], [number:1] etc.

> And task is:
> *to write a PLSQL function which changes parameters in Table_A with the values of Table_B.*

So, result should be:

| A_ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My name is John, and surname Smith |
| 2 | I live in LA |
| ... | ... |

P.S. the solution for the problem would be better, but any directions in which I should move on also will be a plus.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include: **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt that you need help debugging. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one very basic solution. Add more substitution values as needed - one additional outer join per "number" is needed. Suppose you support up to 20 "number" values then you'll need 20 outer joins.

```
WITH table_a (a_id, text) AS
(SELECT 1, 'My name is {0}, and surname {1}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'I live in [city:0]' FROM DUAL 
),
table_b (b_id, a_id, nr, val) AS
(
 SELECT 1, 1, 0, 'John' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 1, 1, 'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 2, 0, 'LA' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT --a.a_id, 
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'([[[:alpha:]]+:)([[:digit:]])(])','{\2}')
       ,'{0}',b0.val)
       ,'{1}',b1.val) as parsed_val
  FROM table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b0 ON a.a_id = b0.a_id AND b0.nr = 0
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b1 ON a.a_id = b1.a_id AND b1.nr = 1;

PARSED_VAL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------
My name is John, and surname Smith
I live in LA
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` statement replaces strings like city:0], [name:1] with {0} and  {1} so only those strings need to be substituted.

Comment: By that I mean, what important is the number inside the brackets. Knowing the number, you substitute by according value.

Comment: What if I have more that 1000 rows, how it could be can automated, without writing every string which should be substituted?

Comment: You have to be more clear in your question. If there is a string [city:1], a string [number:1] and a string [bla:1] - is the functionality exactly the same ? The number of rows doesn't matter, it's the number of substitions withing a single string. From what I understand: {0}, [city:1] and [number:1] are treated the same. Is that correct ? Please give as much info as possible and be as precise as possible.

Comment: Yes the same,  because number inside the brackets is the same. Therefore, they'll be substituted with the same string.
{0}, [city:0], [name:0] will be treated the same, if their id's are the same. Their corresponding string will be in a row with, for ex, id=455, number=0,string='John'.
And for {1}, [city:1], [name:1], corresponding string will be the same, if id's are equal, because all three will have the same number which is 1 in this case.